# Is this graphic about female executives accurate?

Tags: united-states, economics, gender

Is this graph about female executives accurate?

[image: Graphic about salary differences between men and women]

> Women in executive positions earn *18% less* than the average male executive.
>
> This is why:
>
> - 70% Allocative hiring:  only *3.7%* of all CEOs and *2.3%* of all executive chairmen positions are female.
> - 22% Smaller companies:  companies that women worked for are worth *10% less* than the typical company.
> - 7% Age difference:  men in executive positions were both about *five years older* and had *five years more experience* working than females.
> - 1% (Unknown)
>
> You're welcome
>   ifunny.co

(Emphasis and snark copied from the original.  Format adjusted for text.)

The claims seem to be

- Women earn 18% less than men on average, both in executive positions.
- Only 3.7% of CEOs are women.
- Only 2.3% of executive chairs are women.
- That companies for which female executives worked are worth 10% less than all companies.  Bases unspecified (is a company with two female executives counted twice).
- That the average male executive is about five years older than the average female executive.
- And with five years more work experience.
- That the statistics about the age difference, company size, and allocative hiring explain 99% of the pay difference.  Method unspecified--possibly linear regression.

Comment: What graph is it?

Comment: The graphic is about female executives but you were asking about female CEOs.  I'm guessing that you thought that all executives were CEOs, so when I edited the question, I went that way.  If you actually meant to ask just "Are only 3.7% of CEOs women?" please change the title and replace the section starting "The claims seem to be" with "Is it true that only 3.7% of CEOs are women?"  Or similar.

Comment: Where?  Worldwide?

Comment: Why do the women have some kind of extension sticking out of their head?

Comment: Even if the stats are true, I fail to see how there being so few female executives relates to their pay.

Comment: @gerrit A hair bun, probably.

Comment: Executive compensation seems to be 100% subjective and crony-based in it's determination.  It would be very difficult to try and apply any kind of objective standard and determine root cause, even if you believe, as I do, that there probably is some built in bias behind the overall discrepancy.  Feeling and proving are world's apart.  I guess that's why OP is merely asking about the accuracy of the graphic.

Comment: @fredsbend English language Wikipedia gives the impression those are [mostly worn by men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun_(hairstyle)) but I believe that is inaccurate (article is not the greatest, to say the least).

Comment: @fredsbend I believe the claim is that women are rarer in the top two executive level jobs - chair and CEO, than as executives in general; although they don't give a percentage for the latter.

Comment: Poster is a mess. No indication how these things explain lower compensation - especially not 'Allocative hiring'.

Comment: Where is the picture claiming it gets its figures from?

Comment: This is too broad (and the title a mess). Can we pick *one* of these claims please, so it is answerable?

Comment: @Oddthinking I think all of the claims are need to be addressed. I will split the question. How many questions should I split it into?

Comment: Could track down the source of three claims, one is regarding "3.7% of the CEOs were female" present here-https://www.forbes.com/sites/shelliekarabell/2015/08/03/daughters-and-leadership-influencing-the-ceo/#3bf0bbd31631, "The hourly wages of female employees are currently about 18% lower than men’s on average" present here-https://www.ifs.org.uk/uploads/publications/bns/bn186.pdf and "Percent of Global Companies with a Female Chair 2.3%" present here-http://www.calstrs.com/sites/main/files/file-attachments/gmiratings_wob_042013-1.pdf.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin pick one claim, the most important, and focus the question on that. Leave the other claims for later, let's tackle them specifically. Are they all equally notable?

Comment: Also: is the infographic notable? Where does it come from? Am I correct in assuming the claims are about the United States?

Comment: Note that these factors are not independent.  Note the first piece of data--male executives are on average older.  Older = higher salary and older = more likely to be in the top spot.  Yet I see nothing about the effects of this.